# How to create a factory for model with more than one Genereic Foreign Key?

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I am trying to setup a factory for my model that has more than 1 generic foreign key. I can't get to work it for more than one GFK.

```
class ContactFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        # model = ContactData
        exclude = ['content_object']
    object_id = factory.SelfAttribute('content_object.id')
    content_type = factory.LazyAttribute(
        lambda o: ContentType.objects.get_for_model(o.content_object))
    email = factory.Faker('email')
    fax_number = factory.Faker('phone_number')
    phone_number = factory.Faker('phone_number')
    mobile_number = factory.Faker('phone_number')
    external_profiles = factory.Dict({
        'xing': factory.Faker('uri'),
        'website': factory.Faker('uri'),
        'facebook': factory.Faker('uri'),
        'linkedin': factory.Faker('uri')
    })
```

```
class CandidateFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidate
    # id = uuid.uuid4()
    object_id = factory.Sequence(int)
    created_at = FuzzyDateTime(datetime.datetime(2008, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.UTC))
    updated_at = FuzzyDateTime(datetime.datetime(2008, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.UTC))
```

```
class CandidateContactFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    content_object = factory.SubFactory(CandidateFactory)

    class Meta:
        model = ContactData
```

I tried to create an Contact Factory which can be done with

```
b = CandidateContactFactory()
```

But i have a Generic Foreign Key to another `address` model. How can I do so with factory boy?